# Hadoop - constructor args for mapper

Tags: java, scala, hadoop

Is there any way to give constructor args to a Mapper in Hadoop?  Possibly through some library that wraps the Job creation?

Here's my scenario:

```
public class HadoopTest {

    // Extractor turns a line into a "feature"
    public static interface Extractor {
        public String extract(String s);
    }

    // A concrete Extractor, configurable with a constructor parameter
    public static class PrefixExtractor implements Extractor {
        private int endIndex;

        public PrefixExtractor(int endIndex) { this.endIndex = endIndex; }

        public String extract(String s) { return s.substring(0, this.endIndex); }
    }

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Extractor extractor;

        // Constructor configures the extractor
        public Map(Extractor extractor) { this.extractor = extractor; }

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String feature = extractor.extract(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(feature), new Text(value.toString()));
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (Text val : values) context.write(key, val);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "test");
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

As should be clear, since the Mapper is only given to the `Configuration` as a class reference (`Map.class`), Hadoop has no way to pass a constructor argument and configure a specific Extractor.

There are Hadoop-wrapping frameworks out there like Scoobi, Crunch, Scrunch (and probably many more I don't know about) that seem to have this capability, but I don't know how they accomplish it.  **EDIT:** After some more working with Scoobi, I discovered I was partially wrong about this.  If you use an externally defined object in the "mapper", Scoobi requires that it be serializable, and will complain at runtime if it isn't.  So maybe the right way is just to make my `Extractor` serializable and de-serialize it in the Mapper's setup method...

Also, I actually work in Scala, so Scala-based solutions are definitely welcome (if not encouraged!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've come up with so far is to pass a serialized version of the object I want to the Mapper, and to use reflection to construct the object at runtime.

So, the main method would say something like:

```
conf.set("ExtractorConstructor", "dicta03.hw4.PrefixExtractor(3)");
```

Then, in the Mapper we use a helper function `construct` (defined below) and can say:

```
public void setup(Context context) {
    try {
        String constructor = context.getConfiguration().get("ExtractorConstructor");
        this.extractor = (Extractor) construct(constructor);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

---

Definition of `construct` that uses reflection to recursively construct an object at runtime from a String:

```
public static Object construct(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException {
    if (s.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9.#]+\\(.*\\)$")) {
        Class cls = null;
        List<Object> argList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        int parenCount = 0;
        boolean quoted = false;
        boolean escaped = false;
        int argStart = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (escaped) {
                escaped = false;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '\\') {
                escaped = true;
            } else if (s.charAt(i) == '"') {
                quoted = true;
            } else if (!quoted) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == '(') {
                    if (cls == null)
                        cls = Class.forName(s.substring(0, i));
                    parenCount++;
                    argStart = i + 1;
                } else if (s.charAt(i) == ')') {
                    if (parenCount == 1)
                        argList.add(construct(s.substring(argStart, i)));
                    parenCount--;
                } else if (s.charAt(i) == ',') {
                    if (parenCount == 1) {
                        argList.add(construct(s.substring(argStart, i)));
                        argStart = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Object[] args = new Object[argList.size()];
        Class[] argTypes = new Class[argList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < argList.size(); i++) {
            argTypes[i] = argList.get(i).getClass();
            args[i] = argList.get(i);
        }
        Constructor constructor = cls.getConstructor(argTypes);
        return constructor.newInstance(args);
    } else if (s.matches("^\".*\"$")) {
        return s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
    } else if (s.matches("^\\d+$")) {
        return Integer.parseInt(s);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot construct " + s);
    }
}
```

(This may not be the most robust parser, but it could easily be extended to cover more types of objects.)

Comment: @dhj - isn't it more or less the same solution as I mentioned in the response except that you are sending additional parameters to the class to be instantiated?

Comment: Yes, it is.  At first your idea seemed too limited, and that there must be a more general solution out there.  So I thought about it for a while and came up with this.  Then looking back at yours I saw that I had basically come up with an extended model of what you had proposed.

Comment: @dhj - `pass a serialized version of the object` - I don't see any ser/deser - a class name and some additional arguments are sent and a class is created using Class#forName.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest telling your mapper which extractor to use via the `Configuration` object you're creating. The mapper receives the configuration in its `setup` method (`context.getConfiguration()`). It seems like you can't put objects in the configuration as it is usually constructed from XML files or the command line, but you could set an enum value and have the mapper construct its extractor itself. Not very pretty to customize the mapper after its creation, but that's how I interpreted the API.

Comment: +1. This is basically how my team does it. (We use the old API, so it's `MapReduceBase.configure(JobConf)` for us, but the new API's `Mapper.setup(Context)` is the same idea.)

Comment: Yeah, while that would work, it requires preloading the Mapper with all possible configurations that it might ever want.  Since this strategy would make the application pretty inflexible, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: It's true that this pattern is not pretty if you want to parametrize the extraction strategy - you'll have to do a `switch(configuration.get("strategy")) { }` or something similar, and know all the possible classes in advance. However, I like to think of mappers as command line utils that come packaged with a limited set of options. You could design your extractor class hierarchy as you like, and make your mapper a wrapper for it. (The configuration is however well suited for passing parameters like "prefixLength=3", rather than doing it by subclassing like in your answer.)

Comment: Right, the example here is a bit trivial, and configuration would be an easy solution.  But in my real application I want to be able to write arbitrarily complex `Extractor` classes of all shapes and sizes to run experiments in different scenarios.  If I have to have an enum for every combination of `Extractor` possibilities, things will get out of hand very quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Set the implementation classname while submitting the job as

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("PrefixExtractorClass", "com.my.class.ThreePrefixExtractor");
```

or use the [-D option](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options) from the command line to set the PrefixExtractorClass option.

Below is the implementation in the mapper

```
Extractor extractor = null;
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException
{
    try {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        String className = conf.get("PrefixExtractorClass");
        extractor = Class.forName(className);
    } Catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        //handle the exception
    }
}
```

Now use the `extractor` object as required in the map function.

- The jar containing the `com.my.class.ThreePrefixExtractor` class should be distributed to all the nodes. Here is an [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) from Cloudera on different ways of doing this.
- In the above example `com.my.class.ThreePrefixExtractor` should extend the `Extractor` class.

Using this approach the mapper implementation can be made generic. This is the approach (using Class.forName) taken by most of the frameworks to have pluggable components which implement a particular interface.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem; it only moves it.  I want to avoid having a separate class for every potential Extractor implementation by allowing an Extractor instance to be injected at runtime.

Comment: shouldn't it be `Class.forName(...).getInstance()`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking for good answers, but one (non-ideal) solution I came up with is to use inheritance instead of composition, turning Map into an Extractor abstract class.  Then it could be subclassed all the way down to incorporate all constructor args (shown below).

```
    public static abstract class Extractor extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String feature = extract(value.toString());
            context.write(new Text(feature), new Text(value.toString()));
        }

        public abstract String extract(String s);
    }

    public static abstract class PrefixExtractor extends Extractor {
        public String extract(String s) { return s.substring(0, getEndIndex()); }

        public abstract int getEndIndex();
    }

    public static class ThreePrefixExtractor extends PrefixExtractor {
        public int getEndIndex() { return 3; }
    }
```

However, this isn't nearly as nice, and I really feel like there must be a way to do it the right way.

(I moved this out of the original question to make things a bit less cluttered.)

Answer (score 0):

For another similar solution take a look at:

https://github.com/NICTA/scoobi/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/nicta/scoobi/impl/rtt/ClassBuilder.scala

for how we do it. It uses reflection to build some java-source-code that when run would create an identical object graph. We then compile that source (using javassist) and include in the jar that's sent to the cluster.

It's pretty robust if you want to jack it, it handles stuff like cyclic object graphs and all the special cases (there's a fair few).